# How to read/write String from/to .txt?

Tags: java, file, io

I've got some text in a text file. I want to read it from file (first string - first line in file etc.), do something with it and then write to another text file.

How to do it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: With al due respect your questions will be better received if you add what you have tried before

Comment: however I do not  learn Java. I just need one program today.And that's all.

Comment: @Артём Царионов: So you want to use Java without knowing how to use it? Good luck with that!

Comment: maybe. I doubt that anybody wants to do it. So I do it how I can.

Comment: @Артём Царионов - you'd be better off either learning Java properly, or hiring a consultant.  Or using a programming language that you already understand.  (Would you ring up a doctor and ask him for instructions on how to take out your own tonsils?)

Comment: I just need one program and that is all. I do not whant to learn Java now. My program is almost done.
If C# had generator of BigIntegers(not in Mono) I would use it.

Comment: Sorry but this is a typical "fix my code I don't know what is going on" kind of question and thus not well suited as a stackoverflow question.

Comment: ok. I've solved the problem./

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
  String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, contents, "UTF-8");
```

And the best way to find out how that is done internally (in case you are interested) is to look at [the source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java.html) for these two methods.

Comment: While probably correct (I didn't upvote nor downvote), I don't think a person who doesn't even know basic Java I/O is going to be familiar with the Apache Commons™ libraries, nor how to download it and make it work with the rest of the OP's code.

Comment: True, but no one should be made to suffer through the low-level Java I/O APIs. And learning about how to find and use jar files is extremely important.

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) -> use this for reading content from file(there are lots of other ways as mentioned by others,but i find this one the simplest.)

[java.io.PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) -> use for writing into file(other ways also possible,as mentioned above)

Comment: kindly follow the hyperlink ,i forgot to add it but @Jeffrey added it ,thanks to him...

Comment: it doesn't see my file.(NetBeans) `Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));`

Comment: use the complete path like "\path\to\folder\filename.txt"

Comment: printwriter always `PrintWriter filer=new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Чак\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\test1.txt");` gives me "filenotfoundexception" even with files that scanner sees.

Answer (score 1):

You exactly have to do what other folks have mentioned. But here I will be bit detailed and provide you with some code sample.

To open and read the file:

```
String fileName = "paper.txt"; // file to be opened

try {
    Scanner fileData = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while(fileData.hasNextLine()){
        String line = fileData.nextLine();
        line = line.trim();


        if("".equals(line)){
            continue;
        } // end if

    } // end while

    fileData.close(); // close file
}  // end try

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Error message    
} // end catch
```

To write to the text file you can use the following code:

```
boolean fileOpened = true;

try {
    PrintWriter toFile = new PrintWriter("paper.txt");
} // end try

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       fileOpened = false;      
    // Error Message saying file could not be opened        
} // end catch

if(fileOpened){
    toFile.println("String to be added to the file");
    toFile.close();
} // end if
```

I hope this will help you out to solve your problem.